# Do hydraulic road brake levers exist that do not include shifters or dropper post buttons?

Tags: brakes

I have a single speed bike (Genesis Day One ~2013) with mechanical disc brakes.

I would like to upgrade to hydraulic disc brakes.

Do hydraulic road brake levers exist that do not include shifters or dropper post buttons?

Shimano & SRAM levers appear to all be designed to work with their geared groupsets. Magura don't appear to do road bike brakes.

Comment: Another consideration is dual piston mechanical brakes, such as TRP Spyre. You can get a lot of power out of these, even Sram BB7 with decent brake pads and rotors are powerful.

Comment: Do you ride on the hoods/drops?   Or do you ride on the tops mostly ?   Would normal MTB hydraulic levers on the tops be a workable solution for your riding position ?

Comment: Mostly on the hoods probably.

Comment: Deffo plenty of options out there, just have to decide on cost, practicality and convenience

Comment: @Criggie MTB bars have a grip diameter of 22.2mm, while road bikes have 23.8mm. Won’t be a perfect fit.

Comment: @MaplePanda there are so many standards, who knows what sizes are on the table.  And shims can fill some small gaps like that.   (I'd not shim a 31.6mm thing onto a 25.4mm bar though)

Comment: I don't know that it's worth adding as an answer, but there are triathlon hydraulic levers that go into the end of bullhorn bars. I've seen a few people riding single speeds/fixies with bullhorns. This might be an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently only the TRP Hylex.

Comment: I had Magura brakes on a drop-bar bike, which were purely hydraulic with no shifter functions.  Its long gone so I can't get the models, sorry.

Comment: Magura HS66 are the levers. There is also a page of a guy converting a normal Magura lever to drop. https://www.shapeways.com/product/WHZMFF8ER/magura-brake-lever-adapter-for-road-bike-drop-bar

Answer (score 7):

Currently, TRP Hylex are one of the only drop bar brake lever (without gears) that has a hyraulic master cylinder. Magura HS66 is another, but these are pretty rare.

Other options include:

**Cable actuated hydraulic calipers.** These are connected by cables just like normal caliper but the hydralic master cyclinder is at the caliper end, so any drop lever will work. TRP Hy/Rd are the most popular version of these, but other cheaper brads also exist.

Yokozuna Motoko Cable-Pull Hydraulic Disc Brake

[image]

**Cable actuated master cylinders.** These as master cycliders which are attached to the stem or handlebars and are also actuated by cables, so any drop lever will work. Examples of this are Giant's Conduct and Hope Tech V Twin System

Giant Conduct

[image]

Hope V-Twin

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A little update, it looks like there is a new possibility since the publication of the question, from SRAM in the APEX 1 range - gravel. https://www.sram.com/en/sram/models/db-apx-a1